# How to configure rtsp-over-http using MobileVLCKit in Swift?

Tags: swift, rtsp, libvlc

I want to play `rtsp://username:password@domain:2081/0/onvif/profile1/media.smp`. I'm already using VLC to display rtsp or m3u8 streams with no issue.

This is not normal RTSP url. It can be only play with rtsp-over-http tunneling. I confirmed same with VLC Desktop app.